# New to Excel, #REF! Error Doesn't Make Sense to Me.

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm editing a spreadsheet for someone, changing a matrix they built from 7x7 to 5x5. I need to change some formulas to reflect this change, but after I specify the new area in said formula it gives me a #REF! error. The only thing that has changed is the dimensions of the martix, which is why I can't figure out why it would give me that error. The formula is as follows:

```
=INDEX(RAM!I$3:O$9,ABS(7-N4+1),R4)
```

The change would be I$3 -> I$5, O$9 -> M$9.

For what it's worth I also changed the 7 to a 5 (I believe this is needed for the calculation to be correct, but shouldn't be relevant to this issue if I'm not mistaken)

If more info is needed please let me know, I've not had to work in excel for a very long time so I'm not as comfortable with it.

Comment: What are the values of `N4` and `R4`?

Comment: @tigeravatar in this specific instance they are 4 and 6 respectively, but for each cell that I need to put this in those will be different (i.e. N5 R5, N6 R6, etc.)

Comment: The 6 is the problem.  If your area is 5x5, then the only legal values are 1-5 in both cells.  If it's anything other than 1-5, like a 6, you'll get the #REF! error because there is no 6th column or 6th row to return from your area.